# commandButton not generating request, but working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'am facing a strange situation were I have a commandButton (I have tried both standard h:commandButton and primefaces one p:commandButton), when the button is clicked a method in the backing bean is invoked and an Excel file is returned.This command button is inside a dialog, however I think this shouldn't affect.

Problem is that it seems that this button isn't generating any request, at least firebug doesn't show it, but I get the Excel file from the server, which doesn't make sense if there were no requests.

```
<h:commandButton id="downloadButton" value="Download" action="#{bean.downloadExcel}"/> 
<p:commandButton id="downloadButton" value="Download" action="#{bean.downloadExcel}" ajax="false" onsuccess="confirmDialogWv.close();"/>
```

I don't use both buttons at the same time, just tested with both of them with same result.

What is the problem if "everything is working fine"? I can't close the dialog with an onsuccess event if I don't have any request.

Has someone faced this problem before? Any explanation?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:

```
<h:form id="contentForm" prependId="false" >
<!-- lot of code -->
<p:dialog id="confirmDialog"
              modal="true" 
              closable="false" 
              widgetVar="confirmDialogWv" 
              resizable="false"
              header="Confirm">

            <p:commandButton id="downloadButton" value="Download" action="#{bean.downloadExcel}" ajax="false" onsuccess="confirmDialogWv.close();"/> 
            <p:commandButton id="openHtmlButton" value="Open HTML" process="@form" update="@form" actionListener="#{bean.openHtml}"/>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

The second button opens a new window and works properly.

UPDATE:

As already said firebug doesn't show any request, but I've been testing now with IE and Chrome.

Chrome: Shows the request, but when I get the Excel file in the browser the status of the request becomes "canceled".

IE9: Shows the request and returns code 200, but the onsuccess event isn't triggered

Comment: Are your buttons inside a form within the dialog ?

Comment: @Andy yes, the dialog is inside a form

Comment: Can you put bit more of your code? With the form and a dialog?

Comment: @jedrus07 there you have the important part

Comment: Just an obvious question (since it often happens) you do not have any nested forms?

Comment: @jedrus07 I was sure that I don't, but just in case I did a search and now I can confirm that I don't have nested forms

Comment: In the first button isn't this typo ` action="#{bean.downloadExcel} ajax="false"`. It should be ` action="#{bean.downloadExcel}"` and  `ajax="false"` isn't it?

Comment: Sure, sorry problems pasting it here. I will edit it right now. But in the real code it is correct

Comment: You can filter type of requests by "all", documents, images, scripts, styles, XHR, etc. Apparently your filter was set in such way that XHR requests are not visible. As to the download problem, you can't download files by ajax. Likely you was experimenting too much and not running the code you think you was running. I do at least not see any problems related to JSF.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the tip of the XHR requests, I will check that. But I don't have problems downloading the file, I receive the file in the browser and can download it (please notice that I have ajax="false" in  p:commandButton) the problem is that I don't see any request and the onsuccess event is not fired. Mmm the truth is that this event is only available on Ajax requests right? I don't know the behaviour when ajax="false" and onsuccess are present in the same button. Problem is that there isn't any other "standard" event to know when the request is finished, right?

Comment: Oh your concrete problem is thus that the `onsuccess` is never invoked? That wasn't clear from the question at all. It's indeed only invoked on ajax requests (see also tag documentation). Look at PrimeFaces `<p:fileDownload>` for the solution. It supports a callback handler.

Comment: @BalusC sorry, I thought this sentence "What is the problem if "everything is working fine"? I can't close the dialog with an onsuccess event if I don't have any request." would clarify my problem, but seems it didn't. Anyway, your comment above solved my problem. Maybe you can post it as an answer so I can check it as resolved?

Comment: This question seems to suggest that the primary problem is that the command button did not generate any request, but this is untrue.